# How to pass a static array of custom_object type as a parameter to another custom object in C?

Tags: c

Here are my custom objects:

```
typedef struct sem_holder
{
    sem_t *writer_sem;
    sem_t *reader_sem;
} sem_holder;

typedef struct worker_arg
{
    unsigned int nsegments;
    size_t segsize;
    sem_holder *sems;
} worker_arg;
```

Here is my code, where I  pass a &sems argument to the custom objects above:

```
  sem_holder *sems[nsegments];
  sem_holder sems_obj;
  char sem_write_name[21];
  char sem_read_name[21];
  sem_t *writer_sem;
  sem_t *reader_sem;

  ftruncate(DATA_CHANNEL_ID, segsize * nsegments);
  for (int i = 0; i < nsegments; i++)
  {
    // Map subsection of data-channel to an array in proxy's virtual memory
    // processes[i] = mmap(NULL, sizeof(segsize), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 
DATA_CHANNEL_ID, i * segsize);

    // Dynamically create reader and writer names
    snprintf(sem_write_name, 21, "%dw", i);
    snprintf(sem_read_name, 21, "%dr", i);

    // Create a likewise array for semaphores
    writer_sem = sem_open(sem_write_name, O_CREAT, 0660, 0);
    if (writer_sem == SEM_FAILED)
      printf("FAILED\n");
    sems_obj.writer_sem = writer_sem;

    reader_sem = sem_open(sem_read_name, O_CREAT, 0660, 0);
    if (reader_sem == SEM_FAILED)
      printf("FAILED\n");
    sems_obj.reader_sem = reader_sem;

    sems[i] = &sems_obj;
  }

  // Initialize worker arg
  worker_arg worker_arg = {.nsegments = nsegments, .segsize = segsize, .sems = &sems};
```

When I do &sems, I get this error:

```
webproxy.c: In function ‘main’:
webproxy.c:209:80: error: initialization of ‘sem_holder *’ {aka ‘struct sem_holder *’} from incompatible pointer type ‘sem_holder * (*)[(sizetype)(nsegments)]’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  209 | egments, .segsize = segsize, .sems = &sems};
      |
```

When I do just sems, I get this error:

```
webproxy.c: In function ‘main’:
webproxy.c:209:80: error: initialization of ‘sem_holder *’ {aka ‘struct sem_holder *’} from incompatible pointer type ‘sem_holder **’ {aka ‘struct sem_holder **’} [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  209 | segsize = segsize, .sems = sems};
      |
```

Seems it is likely an issue with the way I declare my worker_arg sems parameter. I am just uncertain how I would store this sem_holder array in my worker_arg object. I figured passing a pointer to the object would work but it does not seem to. Any ideas or thought processes that could help?

---

edit, here is my updated code. I am able to pass the sems object now which is good. The value of these semaphores is always 0 though, which is not what I declared it as in sem_open. Clearly I am a novice in C

```
  // char *processes[nsegments];
  sem_holder sems[nsegments];
  char sem_write_name[21];
  char sem_read_name[21];
  sem_t *writer_sem;
  sem_t *reader_sem;

  ftruncate(DATA_CHANNEL_ID, segsize * nsegments);
  for (int i = 0; i < nsegments; i++)
  {
    // Map subsection of data-channel to an array in proxy's virtual memory
    // processes[i] = mmap(NULL, sizeof(segsize), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, DATA_CHANNEL_ID, i * segsize);

    // Dynamically create reader and writer names
    snprintf(sem_write_name, 21, "%dw", i);
    snprintf(sem_read_name, 21, "%dr", i);

    // Create a likewise array for semaphores
    writer_sem = sem_open(sem_write_name, O_CREAT, 0660, 10);
    if (writer_sem == SEM_FAILED)
      printf("FAILED\n");
    sems[i].writer_sem = writer_sem;

    reader_sem = sem_open(sem_read_name, O_CREAT, 0660, 10);
    if (reader_sem == SEM_FAILED)
      printf("FAILED\n");
    sems[i].reader_sem = reader_sem;
  }

  // Initialize worker arg
  worker_arg worker_arg = {.nsegments = nsegments, .segsize = segsize, .sems = sems};
```

Comment: Note: **All** `sems` will point at the same object (`sems_obj`). That object will also be destroyed at the end of the function. I think you want dynamic allocation here.

Comment: Note: you seem to be using the word "static" to mean "not dynamically allocated", but that's confusing.  To me, and I'm sure to many others, calling it "static" suggests use of the `static` keyword and / or static storage duration, but neither of those seems to apply to the array you're talking about.

Comment: The function runs indefinitely for the purpose of this project, and where I am passing it to is within the same process. So the memory should still be present in the stack no?

Comment: And noted about static keyword, I did not know how else to refer to it

Comment: _"So the memory should still be present in the stack no?"_ - What use is it if you make all `sems` point at exactly the same instance?

Comment: Yup I agree, I was just drafting it up while debugging and that was a dumb mistake. Should be fixed, I posted the new code for those curious in an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `sems` as `sem_holder *sems[nsegments];` which means that sems is an array of *pointers* to `sem_holder` structures.

What you want is a simple array so you can declare it like this:

`sem_holder sems[nsegments];`

The compiler indeed tells you that the pointers are incompatible, because what you are doing is basically the following:

```
int* p;
int* pp;

p = pp
```

Answer (score 1):

This ...

> ```
> typedef struct worker_arg
> {
>     unsigned int nsegments;
>     size_t segsize;
>     sem_holder *sems;
> } worker_arg;
> ```

... declares member `worker_arg.sems` as a pointer to a `sem_holder`.  That can accommodate an array in the sense that the pointed-to `sem_holder` can be the first in an array of such, and the others can then be accessed through the same pointer.

On the other hand, this ...

> ```
>   sem_holder *sems[nsegments];
> ```

... declares `sems` as an array of *pointers to* `sem_holder`.  Any one element of that array could be assigned to a `worker_arg.sems`, but that would not provide access to the other elements of `sems`.  The type of this `sems` array does not seem to be compatible with what you want to do.

Note also that *you set every member of `sems` to the same value*, `&sems_obj`.  You modify the object that they all point to on each iteration of the loop, which is surely not what you really want to do.

It looks like you want this ...

```
      sem_holder sems[nsegments];  // array of sem_holder, not of pointers
      // sem_holder sems_obj;      // not needed and probably not wanted
```

... then in your loop, replace references to `sems_obj` with `sems[i]`.

After that, this ...

```
  worker_arg worker_arg = {.nsegments = nsegments, .segsize = segsize, .sems = sems};
```

... will be type correct, *and* (more) semantically correct.

Do note, however, that the `sem_holder` array designated by `sems` lives only until the execution of the block in which it is defined terminates.  That may be fine for you purposes, but if you need it to live longer then you need to dynamically allocate space (e.g. with `malloc()`) rather than using a variable-length array.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, the one I marked best is more succinct to the question I asked. But you made a key point with me using the sems_obj. I only included it while trouble shooting, it is removed now! Also the memory of my array all pointing to the same address is another very helpful tip.